# Working with unsupported browsers [HTML5/CSS3]

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a site, [here](http://www.chrisskillz.com), that I'm working on which uses some html5 and css3 elements which obviously do not load correctly on certain browsers and i have a few questions about what I can do and I don't have much experience with any codes like php or javascript.  these questions are kind of a mess as well - I've been searching all over not really sure of what I should be looking for.

How would I go about creating a popup based on which browser is being used, if possible?

I understand that I can use conditional comments for IE but IE is not the only unsupported browser.  Is there a way to activate certain elements, or div's depending on the browser?

How would I go about creating a version of the site that would be shown instead of the unsupported version?

Is there a better way to do this?

These questions may not be the right ones - if not and you know an answer to the question I'm looking for, please, go for it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few tools I would recommend:

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)

Feature detection, allowing you to target features in CSS and JS. It doesn't add features, just lets you test for them.

Includes HTML5shiv functionality Also does a lot more – if you don't use the other features, then don't use it, it does slow down page loads, but is worth it if you need it!

[HTML5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

Very small, allows you to use html5 elements in IE, nothing else.

[CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

Lets you use border-radius, gradients and box shadow in older versions of IE. Also can allow PNGs in IE 6. Adds a noticeable delay to page load.

[ie7.js (and ie9.js)](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Gives you many CSS3 selectors, min and max width, multiple classes and fixed positioning. Also can have a png fix if you like. Doesn't seem to slow things down much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [moderizer script](http://www.modernizr.com/) to bridge the gap for html markup.

I wouldn't really worry about CSS3 working or not in IE. If you have a supported browser you get an enhanced user experience and if you don't you would just get a normal one.