# Self-developed unsupported scripting fallback in modern internet browsers vs offered products

Tags: javascript, frameworks, cross-browser, fallback

ladies and gentleman.

I would like to know the best way to implement following use-case of Client-Side (G)UI functionality.

**Consider the following:**

- User enters my developed website (further- "website").
- Once it hits correspdoing browsers website loading button afterebtering itsd URL in addressbar, page starts loading.
- The iss, scripts, stylesheets and so on are executed. But - question - how to manage those users that have custom scripting capabilities? For that we need to provide scripting feature fallback if particular feature is not supported by browser ( agent, os, etc. ). So - the MAIN Question - how to provide best fallback capability?

My guess is this:

Framework UI ( jQuery UI x.x ) -> non-UI framework ( jQuery minimized ) -> non-framework ( vanilla JS ) -> DOM ( XPath ) -> redirect to html version.

Is this correct ( and effective ) or am I missing some point?

---

Related topic: [Working with unsupported browsers [HTML5/CSS3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011168/working-with-unsupported-browsers-html5-css3)

Comment: The spelling mistakes are silly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine which browsers you will support. That will then determine what baseline level of code you can write. Don't worry about any "custom scripting capabilities".